# Bloom emitted from a dark material?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, emission

i want (in Eevee) something really simple (i thought) but can't make it work:

I want this bloom effect:
[image]

Combined with this color of the material itself:
[image]

So the "screen" itself should be the darker blue but with the bloom. I played around with the strength and color as well as with the bloom settings a lot. Also tried to make a second plane with the darker material but scaling it a tiny bit down does not work and a little bit in front works neither. Is it impossible?

Comment: Bloom is postprocessed ... if geneated image doesnt contains enough strong emmisive pixels, no bloom is calculated on top of the rendered (real time) image. So use Compositor to generate Glare  and mask screen ... or another option could be set volumetric environment and shout light rays to sides of mmonitor.